# Prevent text from wrapping around awesomefonts image

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an image that is displayed from an awesomefont character with text next to it. The problem I have is I don't want the text to appear under the image, but in right-justification to the right of the image. I've tried using a separate  container and different types of alignment codes, but I can't get it to do what I need.

To view the problem, go to [www.gibsonits.com](http://www.gibsonits.com) and scroll down to the table of 6 points (2 rows, 3 columns). There you will see the text wrapping around the icon.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, **not only on a third-party site**.

Comment: Are you using bootstrap ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add two divs `side by side`  inside wrapper div. In first div, add `font awesome icon` and in second div add text. Look at working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2mxo0d5g/)